# How to get variables data from php to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have following two files and want to get data from php and recieve it in javascript file.

1) **PHP file:**

```
<?php
    $i;
    for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
        echo $i;
    }
?>
```

2) **JavaScript file:**

```
<script>
    var j = -1; 
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            j = this.responseText;
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "www.mywebsite.com/php_file.php", true);

    while(j < 999) {
        xhttp.send();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = j;
    }
</script>
```

Now, the problem is, when run my java script it return me the final value of 'i', but i want to retrieve every value of 'i' while it is in for-loop, like from 0 to 999.. but it return only when php file fully executes it self

Comment: This should be in forloop `echo $j;`

Comment: ricky its different.. it was not used within for loop.. @sahil i did that too but no its not working still getting the final value

Comment: try using  flush();ob_flush(); after echo $i;  you need to flush your buffer after printing your each i value.

Comment: i did but its not useful.. same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your php file as follows : you are outputting j outside of loop

```
<?php
  $i;
  $j = 0;
 for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++){
     $j = $i * $i;
     echo $j;
 } ?>
```

Comment: no its not working.. it return the final echo output... means it return output when whole php executes.

Comment: So, it is problem in js itself . I think the best will be to use ajax.

Comment: i am using ajax in my javascript